# Having errors working with FormData flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, form-data, dio

I have been having a huge failure working with `FormData` using flutter. It works fine while I tested with postman which tells me the error is from my end. I need to post some list of files to the backend along with some parameters as such.

[image]

But it gives me 501 error each time which tells me that some data is invalid, however, there is no way to tell me exactly which parameter the error is located.

```
  Dio dio = new Dio();
 List<Map<String, int>> scheduled_slots = [
    {"dateslot_id": 107, "timeslot_id": 97},
    {"dateslot_id": 121, "timeslot_id": 120}
  ];
List<String> filesPath = ["/data/user/0/com.heckerbella.hope_clinic/app_flutter/1634521427103972"];
List<String> filesName = ["fileName"];
List<String> type =["Burning Pain", "Burning Pain"];
List<String> rating =["Just curious", "Mild Pain"];


    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "type": type,
      "rating": rating,
      "description": widget.description,
      'files': [
        await files.asMap().forEach((index, value) async {
          await MultipartFile.fromFile
            (filesPath[index], filename:
          filesName[index]);
        }),],
     "scheduled_slots": scheduled_slots as String
    });

    try {
      Response response = await dio.post(
          Constants().API_BASE_URL +
              "scheduled/slot/main/create/${selectedPlansData.id}",
          data: formData,
          options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.json, headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer ${bloc.bearerToken}",
            "Accept": "application/json",
          }));
      AlertManager.showToast(response.data.toString());
      print(Constants().API_BASE_URL +
          "scheduled/slot/main/create/${selectedPlansData.id}");
      return response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    
    }
  }
```

**Error**

```
I/flutter (10345): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [501]
I/flutter (10345): #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
I/flutter (10345): #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
I/flutter (10345): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (10345): #2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
I/flutter (10345): <asynchronous suspension>
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(10345): Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10146; state: ENABLED
E/Toast   (10345): setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
```

Answer (score 1):

You have issue with *scheduled_slots*, *Dio* only support fields on *FormData* is *String*, so when you pass a value is *List<Map<String, int>>*, Server will not receive it. Let deal with BE to convert *scheduled_slots* from List -> String.

Comment: how do I convert it?

Comment: please review my updated code. I cast scheduled slots as string but got save error response.

Comment: also did jsonEncode(scheduled_slots). Same result

Comment: but you need ask your BE, when you jsonEncode this information, your BE will need decode to receive data.